# use 'range' inside of an array multiple times in python

Tags: python, arrays, range, concatenation

I looked and couldn't find a similar question probably because I'm a python noob and don't know the proper language to search.

is there a way to do this...

```
frame_inds = [0,  list(range(200, 2000, 100)), 3999]
```

the output I get is this

```
[0, [200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900], 3999]
```

but I want this

```
[0, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 3999]
```

so that it is all in one array?

in matlab you can do this `var1 = [1, 2, 3:10:100, 400]`

Comment: These are lists, not arrays. `array` means something different in Python; usually it's talking about something produced by the third-party Numpy library, although it can also refer to something from the `array` standard library module.

Comment: If you're coming from Matlab, you almost certainly *should* get NumPy, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
frame_inds = [0,  *range(200, 2000, 100), 3999]
```

By using the `*` operator you can unpack all its items and they become items in the main list.

Comment: You don't need to call `list`. That just wastes time and space on a temporary list.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, True, fixed.

Comment: awesome I will accept this answer when it allows me to. need to wait a fe min. I thought list was needed to make it an array of numbers? when is list needed?

Comment: @PhillipMaire, range is an iterator, which means that it works for accessing the items one after the other. You will sometimes see it converted to a list when access is needed by index and not in order, or when you need it more than once (so it's better to create the list once rather than the iterator several times). In this case the `*` operator iterates over the range, so no need to make it a list first.

Comment: `range` isn't actually an iterator. It's a lazy sequence type that generates elements on demand. (Try indexing a range. It works!)

Answer (score 2):

I would simply concatenate the lists, using the `+` operator.

```
frame_inds = [0]+list(range(200, 2000, 100))+[3999]
```

Comment: This will not be efficient, you are creating 5 lists needlessly (4 temporary, because adding two temporaries creates another temporary one, and then the final one)